# TFS 2017 How do I know which test is being run (before it finishes)?

Tags: tfs

I have a TFS 2017 (version 15.105.25910.0) build which also runs tests, but one test is taking a very long time and the whole build is cancelled due to a timeout set in the 'general' tab of the build edit page. TFS log is included below. **How can I check which test is faulty?**

Notice the time difference between the first and second log. I assume a faulty test is being run after `ReportAnalyzer_Blabla_SomethingTest`, but with over 1k tests it's hard to guess which it is.

`2017-08-30T11:30:09.7614471Z Passed   ReportAnalyzer_Blabla_SomethingTest
2017-08-30T11:53:52.1581687Z ##[debug]FindFiles.FindMatchingFiles(rootFolder = D:\TfsBuildAgents\RmsBuild\_work\8\s\TestResults, matchPattern = *.trx, includeFiles = True, includeFolders = False
2017-08-30T11:53:52.1581687Z ##[debug]FindFiles.GetMatchingItems(includePatterns.Count = 1, excludePatterns.Count = 0, includeFiles = True, includeFolders = False
2017-08-30T11:53:52.1581687Z ##[debug]FindFiles.FindMatchingFiles - Found 0 matches
2017-08-30T11:53:52.1581687Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning;code=002003;]
2017-08-30T11:53:52.1581687Z 
2017-08-30T11:53:52.1581687Z 
2017-08-30T11:53:52.1737949Z ##[warning]No results found to publish.
2017-08-30T11:53:52.1737949Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]No results found to publish.
2017-08-30T11:53:52.2050485Z ##[error]The operation was canceled.
2017-08-30T11:53:52.2050485Z ##[debug]System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.`

Comment: Which task did you use to run the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a messy workaround which helped me find the failing test. In **all test classes** (the messy part) I've added a code which appends the currently running unit test name to a file - the last entry was what I was interested in.

```
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void ClassInitialzie(TestContext testContext)
    {
        // This is just an example!
        File.AppendAllText("testRunLog.txt", testContext.TestName + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

The closes thing to "run the code before each test in the whole test project" seems to be the `ClassInitialize` attribute.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Normally the faulty test should be the first test after `ReportAnalyzer_Blabla_SomethingTest`. But as you said, it with over 1k tests, according to the log you posted, if you didn't split the tests we can not exactly identify which test is the faulty one. In this case, I'm afraid that you have to debug that one by one.

So, yo can try to split the tests then debug them accordingly.

You can also try to check if there are any other detailed logs to track that.
See [Review continuous test results after a build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/getting-started/review-continuous-test-results-after-build) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm afraid there are no tests results to browse in case the run is cancelled. `##[warning]No results found to publish.` Additionaly debugging one by one locally sometimes yields different results than running on TFS (some tests are quite old and messy).